# gradle this tasks reference

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to move some extra code to closure and call it in the scope of task, how to do it?

I have something like, and it works fine

```
task AwesomeTest(type: Test) {
   filter {
      setIncludePatterns(filtered as String[])
   }
}
```

but would like to have something like (of course example below doesn't work)

```
task AwesomeTest(type: Test) {
   extraFilter (this)
}

ext.extraFilter = { task ->
   task.filter {
      setIncludePatterns(filtered as String[])
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to `project`. An instance of `Task` is passed as first argument to the closure. You need to name it or use `it`. Here you go:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

ext.extraFilter = { task ->         
   configure(task) {
      filter {
         setIncludePatterns('*')
      }
   }
}

task AwesomeTest(type: Test) { t ->
   extraFilter(t)
}
```

Comment: Hej Maciek, dzięki za pomoc ;) [en] : thanks for help;) it does the job

Comment: Nie ma problemu :) No problem, hope to meet You :D